# Downloaded maps don't appear in multiplayer rotation

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I purchased the "Uprising" DLC for COD Black Ops 2 (PC version), but the new maps are not appearing as part of the online multiplayer maps.

I can select one of the maps via the custom game types, but in matchmaking the maps are not there.

Is it not possible to use these maps in multiplayer matches?

Comment: Do you mean that while playing "Public Match" they aren't appearing as often? or That the "Uprising" playlist is no longer available?

Comment: @ColeBusbyakacheat117cole108 I've only seen a map from Uprising appear in the voting stack once during "Public Match", but people didn't vote for it. I have no "Uprising" playlist. Is there suppose to be one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restarting the client after downloading the maps, Occasionally this happens to me on Xbox, after the DLC is finished installing the game will reload the Multiplayer client. Unless it is the Uprising playlist, in which case the developers have decided to remove it from the Public Match lists and included Uprising to the rotation the same as Nuketown and the like. Other possibility is that Steam saved it into a new location if you have two storage areas for BL2.

Comment: I purchased this item last week, and restarted my PC each day without change. Will the public match interface show me options for DLC that I do not have?

Comment: Uprising is the second DLC to be released to users, it is in the main map rotation on Public Matches and League Play, but to play Online Multiplayer with friends you'll have to play Custom Match to always see them. The problem is that they just released the Vengeance DLC so they will be more prominent, You should also see a "Vengeance" Playlist in the Public Match playlists. I haven't booted Black Ops 2 in a while on PC so I'm basing most of this off my 360 experience. DLC is listed even if you cannot play it but will most likely be in something like "Not yet Owned"

Comment: Yeah, the Uprising playlist was removed from the PC version about a month ago (at the very least). I also bought Uprising late and missed out on Uprising playlist. So far I have only played one of the multi-player maps from this DLC. Frustrating :(